# MacVisibilityChanged() Does not get triggered for Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, migration, wxwidgets

wxWindowMac::MacVisibilityChanged() is virtual method and it is meant to be overridden, but it does not get called in Cocoa, while when using Carbon it was. (There was a migration from Carbon to Cocao).

My guess is that triggering this method via events is not implemented for Cocoa port of wxWidgets. Anyone had the same problem, what was the solution?

I am using wxWidgets 3.0.2 and Mac OS 10.9.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself for this one.

Just add an event handler for wxShowEvent and forget about using wxWindowMac::MacVisibilityChanged.

Comment: This is correct and, more generally, all `MacXXX()` methods are private and you shouldn't be using them in the first place.